# Async/await and promise all not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, firebase-storage

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm having trouble with async/await and promises.
I'm trying to upload an array of images to firebase asynchronously so I get the URLs back for the next step. The following is the upload function.

```
const uploadImage = async (file) => {
            console.log("starting...");
            const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("forum/" + file[1]);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(file[0])
                    .then(async (res) => {
                        console.log("res to blob");
                        return await res.blob();
                    })
                    .then(async (blob) => {
                        blob.name = file[1];
                        console.log("Starting to put file...", blob);
                        await storageRef.put(blob).then(async () => {
                            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
                            urlArray.push(url);
                            console.log(url);
                            !url ? resolve("got url!") : reject("it broke");
                        });
                    });
                console.log("done!");
            });
        };

        const uploadArray = async (imageArray) => {
            return await Promise.all(
                imageArray.map((image) => uploadImage(image))
            );
        };

        uploadArray(project.images).then((urls) => {
            urls.forEach((element) => {
                console.log(element);
            });
        });
```

This is the console every time uploadArray() is called.

````
starting...
done!
starting...
done!
res to blob
Starting to put file... Blob {name: "IMG_3851.JPG", size: 1417851, type: "image/jpeg"}
Starting to put file... Blob {name: "IMG_3852.JPG", size: 2391056, type: "image/png"}
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... (Link to firebase)
Uncaught (in promise) it broke```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... (Link to firebase)
````

But I want the console to log the statements in this order instead.

```
starting
res to blob
Starting to put file... Blob {name: "IMG_3851.JPG", size: 1417851, type: "image/jpeg"}
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... (Link to firebase)
done!
starting
res to blob
Starting to put file... Blob {name: "IMG_3852.JPG", size: 2391056, type: "image/png"}
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... (Link to firebase)
done!
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are handling promises is a bit strange, and has the `new Promise` constructor anti-pattern. I rewrote the messy parts here, and I suspect this will solve your ordering issue:

```
const uploadImage = async (file) => {
   console.log("starting...");
   const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("forum/" + file[1]);
   const res = await fetch(file[0]);
   const blob = await res.blob();
   blob.name = file[1];
   console.log("Starting to put file...", blob);
   await storageRef.put(blob);

   const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
   urlArray.push(url);
   console.log(url);
   if (url) {
      return "got url";
   }
   throw "it broke";
}
```

The snippet above mostly does what you wrote, but all the unnecessary then's removed. It should be a lot clearer. It's *very* worthwhile fully learning promises and async/await before you proceed. The code you shared feels very trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Couple tidbits about JS and async/await:

1. Technically, functions should only be marked as async if it uses `await` inside it - otherwise you might get undefined behavior when errors occur
2. Since you're not awaiting the `fetch`, you're `console.log("done!");` should go after the line where you resolve/reject. It's not so it gets executed immediately, that's why your seeing them printed right after `"starting"`
3. Nowadays, you usually can replace all calls to `.then` with an `await`. Avoiding "callback hell" is very important in JS when it comes to code clarity. Sometimes it's not possible to get around using `new Promise()`, but if it can be avoided, it should be

Like @Evert's answer, removing callbacks and using proper awaits will likely fix your ordering issues.

It would also be a good idea to add a try catch around all the API calls so that you don't get an unhandled promise exception. It can be added to the `uploadImage` method, or to where you call `Promise.all`, whatever works best for your use case.

```
const uploadImage = async (file) => {
  try {
    console.log("starting...");
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("forum/" + file[1]);
    const res = await fetch(file[0]);
  
    console.log("res to blob");
    const blob = await res.blob();
    blob.name = file[1];
  
    console.log("Starting to put file...", blob);
    await storageRef.put(blob);
    const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
    urlArray.push(url);
  
    console.log(url);
    if (!url) throw new Error("it broke");

    console.log("done!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: I haven't heard of your first point before but you got me curious now - could you expound on it a bit? Why would throwing an error in an async function without an await cause undefined behavior?

Comment: I think doing a general try..catch is in this case a bad idea. The idea of exceptions is that they are supposed to bubble up to a point where you can do something useful with them. You are logging the error (useful) but whatever calls uploadImage still thinks it was successful because it basically got a success response.